# Windows 8 boot loop after mounting from linux

Tags: mount, multi-boot, windows-8, boot

I installed the release version of windows 8 professional (which I got through my university). I installed Ubuntu on another drive so I can select which drive to boot in the BIOS. All was well... until I tried mounting my windows partition. I got the following message:

[image: Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 14: Hibernated non-system partition]

I was sure I did not hibernate my system... it must be part of the new hybrid boot thing. I went ahead and ran the suggested command. After all... whats the worst that can happen. I'd probably just lose some saved session information right?... Wrong! Windows 8 now perpetually reboots after showing a brief message about trying to fix itself.

I found that startup repair fails when I run it from the install disk using the [DVD drive] boot device. When I boot the DVD drive as [UEFI DVD drive], startup repair automatically does a system restore and appears to complete successfully... but windows 8 still perpetually reboots.

After some research, I found that the file that my mount command probably deleted was hiberfil.sys in the root directory of the C drive. I tried undeleting it with testdisk but my repeated system restore attempts seem to have overwritten it.

Does anyone else have any ideas on how to get windows to boot again?

Answer (score 1):

I installed windows 8 on another drive. I booted an Ubuntu live cd and mounted my new installation as read-only. Then I copied hiberfil.sys from my new installation to the old windows installation. At this point my old installation was able to successfully repair itself upon restart.

Some programs are missing though.